# Why does Range throw UnsupportedOperationException?

Tags: java, list, collections, groovy, range

While I'm trying to edit **groovy.lang.Range** with subscript operator I have an error `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` whilst for **java.util.List** all goes fine. There're no sign in the [Groovy Range API](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Range.html) that the collection is immutable. Have you any ideas what's wrong with Range\with my code?

The code is below:

```
def list = "a".."c"
assert list instanceof java.util.List
assert list.size() == 3
list[2] = "d"
```

The console output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.set(AbstractList.java:132)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.putAt(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:6607) <6 internal calls>
    at Hello.run(Hello.groovy:4) <15 internal calls>
    at Hello.main(Hello.groovy) <5 internal calls>
```

**Update**:

Groovy Version: 1.8.6 JVM: 1.6.0_45 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Linux

Comment: `java.util.List` is an *interface*. Range may not implement all the methods.

Comment: [`set` is not supported on `Range`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/GROOVY_1_8_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L6609). In order to achieve this, convert the range (in this case an ObjectRange) to a list by using `('a'..'c').toList()`. See AbstractList http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#set(int,%20E) for details.

Comment: Are you sure this class is intended to be mutable?

Comment: @PeterLawrey no, I haven't. It was only the issue dependant proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that groovy uses [ObjectRange](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/ObjectRange.html). In the docs you can see that it inherits the add method from `java.util.AbstractList` which throws the UnsupportedOperation Exception.